# Angular 9/10 TypeError Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at_webpack_require_bootstrap:79

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when I added @angular/material/dialog to may application. I can run the app but the dialog won't load and I get the following error below in the Console: I tried upgrading from Angular 9 to 10 but get the same issue. I also tried this in another app and the exact same thing occurred.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded bootstrap and this seemed to solve it...